# Google Plus "Sign in api" and Splash screen

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

Currently I have 3 activities in my application. The first activity is to load default Splashscreen.class, I would like this activity to check whether the user accessed with your Google+ account "Sign In" on Login.class class.

In short, La Splashscreen.class class to check if the user logged in or not and direct it to one activity or another. I leave my code.

**Splashscreen.class**

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    private boolean mIsBackButtonPressed;
    private static final int SPLASH_DURATION = 2500;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() { 
                finish();

                if (!mIsBackButtonPressed) {
                    /*if(){  If the user is connected go to class Mainactivity.class

                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                    SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
                }
                }else{
                //If the user is not connected go to class Login.class
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);
                        SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
                    }

*/
            }

        }, SPLASH_DURATION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        mIsBackButtonPressed = true;
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

**Login.class**

```
public class Login extends Activity implements OnPageChangeListener,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener{

    /* Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions. */
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    static Context context;
    /* Client used to interact with Google APIs. */
    private static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /* A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents
     * us from starting further intents.
     */
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;
    private boolean mSignInClicked;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

    boolean result_back;
    private ViewPager vp;
    private ViewPagerAdapter vpAdapter;
    private List<View> views;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        initViews();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Plus.API)
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
        .build();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Conectando ...");

        findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in).setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    public void onClick(View view) {
        pDialog.show();
        if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_sign_in
                && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            // Store the ConnectionResult so that we can use it later when the user clicks
            // 'sign-in'.
            mConnectionResult = result;

            if (mSignInClicked) {
                // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to resolve all
                // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // We've resolved any connection errors.  mGoogleApiClient can be used to
        // access Google APIs on behalf of the user.
        pDialog.dismiss();
        mSignInClicked = false;

        //Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getProfileInformation();
        Intent i=new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i); 
    }

    /**
     * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
     * */
    public static void getProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                        .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                currentPerson.getUrl();
                Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

                Toast.makeText(context,"Name: " + personName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }

            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if(mConnectionResult == null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Es null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        }else{
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                startIntentSenderForResult(mConnectionResult.getResolution().getIntentSender(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
                // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
        }
    }


    private void initViews() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        views = new ArrayList<View>();      
        views.add(inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_one, null));
        views.add(inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_two, null));
        views.add(inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_three, null));

        vpAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(views, this);

        vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        vp.setAdapter(vpAdapter);
        vp.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

        CirclePageIndicator indicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.circle);
        indicator.setViewPager(vp);
        indicator.setSnap(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {      
    }

}
```

Thank you all, Greetings!

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: @twntee I would check  from class Splashscreen if the user has logged in with your Google account and accepting the application permissions. If this is true, every time you start the application proceed directly to the Main Activity class and not Login.class